# ERROR: ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: Forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, jenkins-kubernetes

Hi I am trying to integrate kubernates with jenkins using kubernates deployment plugin.i configured all the details correctly and mentioned kubeconfig file in jenkins but it is not running yaml files specifice name space instead it is running default name space and in that default name space i do not have permissions to create deployments.so my question can i mention namespace in below scirpt.

```
script {
kubernetesDeploy(kubeconfigId: 'pmkubeconfig',
configs: 'tomcatprodlocaldemo.yml', 
enableConfigSubstitution: false,
}
```

If i add below property also
`secretNamespace: 'pmicm'` it is running in default namespace.

Comment: Add `namespace` param in `tomcatprodlocaldemo.yml` file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve a time to read the  [**about page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit theses links to learn [**how to ask a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get better and faster answer! please check @hariK suggestion and if it doesn't solve your issue, share the `tomcatprodlocaldemo.yaml` file so we can check and help you trobleshoot.